# Find duplicated values from list o vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have this example data

```
a<-c(1,5,7,8,10,15)
b<-c(2,6,7,9,10,20,31)
```

I need to find the duplicated values (the values which are in both vectors) and create new vector which include these number. It should looks like

```
c<-c(7,10)
```

Because of different length of vector I have tried to give them into list of vectors

```
l<-list(a=a,b=b)
```

and tried

```
duplicated(l)
```

or

```
duplicated(a,b)
```

but it gives nonsense output. I'm looking for correct solution but I cannot still find. Any advices?

Comment: Your comments below indicate that you may have more than 2 vectors to look at simultaneously.  If so, does "duplicated" mean something that appears in all vectors, or just something that appears in more than one of them?

Comment: It means it appears in all of them. Hopefully I have about 10 vectors so I did it step by step by adding another vector by intersect for this moment. I need to move forward in my work, I will be happy to find efficient solution, but I cannot work on it today.

Comment: @Arun's suggestion of `Reduce(intersect, my_list)` is what you want, then.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a job for `intersect()`

```
a<-c(1,5,7,8,10,15)
b<-c(2,6,7,9,10,20,31)
c<-intersect(a,b)
c
[1]  7 10
```

Comment: I see this function doesn't work there should be third vector. Does it?

Comment: The example code above works perfectly in base R.  The only thing I can imagine that would make it not work for you is if it is masked by a different package.  Try `base::intersect(a,b)`.  Am I understanding your comment correctly?

Comment: +1, but I think he is suggesting there could be a third vector he wants to check for duplicates (or more generally, n vectors).

Comment: Ahh.  If so he need to clarify if "duplicates" in that context means something that appears in all three vectors or just more than one.

Comment: `Reduce(intersect, my_list)`??

Comment: @Arun, I deleted my answer after seeing your comment doing so efficiently what I tried to do in what now feels a very clumsy way.

Answer (score 3):

```
c(a, b)[duplicated(c(a, b))]
```

produces:

```
[1]  7 10
```

`duplicated` applied to a vector returns a logical vector of the same length, with `TRUE` for every value that has already appeared earlier in the vector.  You can use that to subset the original vector.

Note that if you don't care if values are duplicated within a single vector, then you should do:

```
a.b <- c(unique(a), unique(b))
a.b[duplicated(a.b)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't care because I have already deleted the duplicated values in each vector.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping within the scope of the original question,

You could use `match`

```
> b[!is.na(match(a, b))]
# [1]  7 10
```

Or more simply, `%in%`

```
> b[a %in% b]
# [1]  7 10
```

Comment: +1, interestingly `intersect` uses `match` internally.

Comment: @BrodieG - thanks.  IMO, this is exactly what `%in%` is for :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating function like

```
duplicated_values<-function(x){
if(x%in%b){
return(x)
}
}
values<-mclapply(c(1:length(a)),duplicated_values)
```